# Unknown Error Occurred (-54) Enabling iTunes Match

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

I just added my Apple ID to a new MacBook Pro and tried to turn on iTunes Match.  This is the error I get:

[image: iTunes Match Error]

The only info I can find indicates this is a connection error, but I can connect to other areas of the iTunes Store.  Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/message/5364651#5364651) or [this one](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16764639#16764639) it seems (-54) is a file-lock problem. The proposed solutions are:

- an AppleScript to remove locks

  > Open the Script Editor in the /Applications/Utilities folder and run the following:
  >   `tell application "Finder"
  >   set locked of every item of entire contents of folder "Music:iTunes" of home to false
  >   end tell`
- use Terminal to ensure ownership, group, and permissions are correct

  - use `sudo chown your-username your-filename` if you don't own the file/folder
  - use `sudo chgrp staff your-filename` if it isn't set to the same group as other iTunes items
  - use `chmod 666 your-filename` and/or `chmod 777 your-folder-name` to make sure everyone (and thing) can edit
- disabling FileVault if used

In particular, check the permissions on the iTunes/Download folder which is where iTunes will first attempt to download "matched" songs.

Comment: Seems like a valid answer so I'm accepting, but unfortunately due to corp policy I'm not able to turn off FileVault.  The AppleScript solution did not work for me either.

Comment: chmod 666/777 is a security issue, especially in a shared/corporate environment. chmod'ing to 600/700 should be enough to avoid any permission issues for the current user.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V62ezBcqLW8) and see if it solves your problem. The intro is annoying, but I hope it helps.

Comment: No, sorry...note in my question I state that I'm using a MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 0):

It's a **permissions denied** error.

- Are you sure your Apple ID hasn't been linked to more  then 5 devices?
- Have you tried to log out- and in again?
- Has iTunes Match worked before?

Comment: How did you arrive from -54 to *permissions denied*?  Might be worthwhile to post a link to whatever source helped you interpret that.

Comment: Answers to your bullets:  yes I'm sure it's not, yes I've tried logging out and back in, yes for my account, but not on this computer.

Comment: I know it's an easy shot, but how about rebooting your Mac or reinstalling iTunes?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the standard disk utility and restored permissions on the tome which contained my iTunes library. That took about a minute and fixed the problem for me.